# Is using multiple halftone screens on the same page allowed in postscript 3?

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I am working with a postscript file that uses `sethalftone` several times on the same page. On my printer I get the expected results but when using ghostscript, the whole page is rendered with the same screen. I reduced it down to this example:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0

<< /PageSize [99 33] >> setpagedevice

/size 33 def

/rect {
newpath
0 0 moveto
size 0 lineto
size size lineto
0 size lineto
closepath
fill
} def

0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 setcmykcolor
rect

<< /HalftoneType 1 /Frequency 100 /Angle 60 /SpotFunction { pop } >> sethalftone
size 0 translate
rect

<< /HalftoneType 1 /Frequency 100 /Angle 45 /SpotFunction { pop } >> sethalftone
size 0 translate
rect

showpage
```

For which `gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -r600 -sDEVICE=tiffsep1 -sOutputFile=test%d.tif test.ps` (version 9.52) gives me the following channel images (its the same for all channels):

[image: All three panels have the same halftone]

When moving the first `sethalftone` before the first `rect` command, I get these channel images, which contain artifacts and still have the same halftone:

[image: Magenta channel]
[image: Black channel]
[image: Cyan channel]
[image: Yellow channel]

Obviously, there is some sort of memory corruption in the halftone buffer.
Setting only one halftone at the beginning (before the default has been used) works fine.

So my question from the title remains: Is it allowed to use multiple different halftones on the same page in postscript?

PS: When separating each rectangle and halftone onto its own page, I still get the memory corruptions but the halftones seem to be applied differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change halftone at any point in the course of a PostScript program. It need not be at the start of a page or start of a program.

Comment: So then I am dealing with a buggy implementation in ghostscript?

Comment: So it would appear, you can raise a bug report at bugs.ghostscript.com

Comment: https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=702893